# Unable to Transfer FSMO Role to Specific Domain Controller

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller, fsmo

I currently have two **Windows 2012 R2 domain controllers** - serverA and serverB. I have two **Windows 2019 instances** that were promoted to domain controllers with DNS roles - serverC and serverD. I was able to transfer the **RID, PDC and Infrastructure roles** from serverA to serverC using the **operations master gui in AD Users and Groups**.

I am trying to transfer the **domain naming master** from serverB to serverD but when I open **Active Directory Domains and Trusts** and select operations master the DC I want to use for this role is **not listed**. I am currently logged in to serverD when I attempt this role transfer which is the DC I want to assign this role to. ServerC is listed but I **don't want** one domain controller to have all of the roles.

ServerA and ServerB are both running and operational, they are **not dead or de-commissioned** servers. I'm not seeing any AD related errors when I run dcdiag or errors in the event viewer logs  of ServerD. Any thoughts on why ServerD isn't listed as an option to transfer this role to or what I might be doing wrong from my end? Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: I always use Ntdsutil.exe to do that. Maybe try that in case there's something up with the way the console is connecting or something. Domain naming master: "This FSMO role holder is only active when the role owner has inbound replicated the configuration NC successfully since the Directory Service started." Maybe you need to wait a while? Does it work now?

Comment: Since the one 2019 instance (ServerD) wasn't showing up as an option when it came to migrating the last two roles I thought I could migrate everything to ServerC and then from there migrate to ServerD using the GUI but ServerD still didnt show up an option. I ultimately ended up using Ntdsutil.exe and it worked fine. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Use the command line tool Ntdsutil.exe instead.